# How to verify file download on docker containers without volumes?

Tags: file, docker, jenkins, selenium-grid, amazon-ecs

I am trying to set up an automation test suit using selenium-grid,docker containers, jenkins and aws-ecs.

The selenium-grid will be setup using aws-ecs. The automation tests will be executed as part of a jenkins pipeline.

The problem is that the test suite contains **file download** tests. I **can not use volumes** since the containers will be spun up on a different machine than the jenkins workspace.

Is there any way I can assert that a file has downloaded? Can a browser instance running in the container provide any confirmation that the file download has started?

Please find below the stepdef I used for verifying file download on a **local** setup.

```
@And("a file called (.*) should be downloaded to my downloads directory")
public void verifyFileDownload(String filename) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    File[] files = new File(DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY).listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            results.add(file.getName());
        }
    }
    assertThat(results.contains(filename), is(true));
}
```

Comment: Are you able to make the download a separate step? Then you won't need to do a test, since the download will be complete when the step finishes, or the step will fail if there is a problem.

Comment: That is exactly what is expected. But how do I check whether the file has downloaded inside the docker container?

Comment: If you do the download manually (`docker exec mycontainer wget ...`) then it will block until complete or failed, and the usual unix return codes apply - zero is successful and non-zero is failed. I assume your whole Jenkins build will fail if a step command fails (which is desirable).

Answer (score 2):

You can go inside your container.
If you know on which server run your container is runnning, you can run

`docker exec -it [container_name] /bin/bash`

And check manually if your file is here.

Comment: The tests run as part of an automation suit. Manually verifying whether a file has downloaded or not isnt possible. I have edited the question to add the step used to verify the same on a local setup. This however is not possible on a cloud infrastructure.

Comment: I could not get this working. So I changed the tests to verify the response code for clicking the download link. Its not exactly what we needed. It is a better workaround.